# Batch replace of files content in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, automation, terraform, devops

I have multiple files under some root directory, let’s call it module/data/.
I need to upload this directory to the corresponding S3 bucket. All this works as expected with:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "k8s-state" {
  for_each = fileset("${path.module}/data", "**/*")
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.kops.bucket
  key    = each.value
  source = "${path.module}/data/${each.value}"
  etag   = filemd5("${path.module}/data/${each.value}")
}
```

The only thing is left is that I need to loop over all files recursively and replace markers (for example `!S3!`) with values from variables of terraform’s module.
Similar to this, but across all files in directories/subdirectories:

```
replace(file("${path.module}/launchconfigs/file"), “#S3”, aws_s3_bucket.kops.bucket)
```

So the question in one sentence: how to loop over files and replace parts of them with variables from terraform?

Comment: Can the files be considered templates? if yes you can use:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/d/file.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An option could be using templates, the code will look like:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-1"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "sample_bucket2222" {
  bucket = "my-tf-test-bucket2222"
  acl    = "private"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "k8s-state" {
  for_each = fileset("${path.module}/data", "**/*")
  bucket   = aws_s3_bucket.sample_bucket2222.bucket
  key      = each.value
  content  = data.template_file.data[each.value].rendered
  etag     = filemd5("${path.module}/data/${each.value}")
}

data "template_file" "data" {
  for_each = fileset("${path.module}/data", "**/*")
  template = "${file("${path.module}/data/${each.value}")}"
  vars = {
    bucket_id  = aws_s3_bucket.sample_bucket2222.id
    bucket_arn = aws_s3_bucket.sample_bucket2222.arn
  }
}
```

Instead of `source` you can see I'm using `content` to consume the template_file, that is the only difference in that resource with yours

---

On your files the variables could be consumed like:

```
Hello ${bucket_id}
```

---

I have all my test code here:
https://github.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/tree/master/TerraForm/regional